# Geom to simple json

Tags: json, postgresql, postgis

I have geom in postgres database. When I use this query

```
SELECT   ST_AsGeoJSON(st_simplify(geom,0.01))::json  As geometry FROM tbl_tehsils
```

the result shows as

```
"{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[72.3847874560001,33.4222288170001],[72.4486151570001,33.390380325], (...)"
```

while I like to create result as

```
[[31.7143740770001,74.6556250200001],[31.256258297,74.244557296]]
```

I am using postgres (postgis).

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the coordinates like this.

```
select ST_AsGeoJSON(st_simplify(geom,0.01))::json->>'coordinates' from tbl_tehsils ;
```